# Question about smooth functions and their signs with given initial conditions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification, alternative-proof, smooth-functions

#### Problem Statement

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function (infinitely differentiable) where $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $f(0)=0$, and $f(1)=1$. Show that there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and an $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{(n)}(x_0)<0$.

#### Proof Attempt

We can consider two cases:

**Case (1):** There exists a $z<0$ such that $f(z)>0$. By the MVT, there exists a point $z_0\in(z,0)$ such that $$f'(z_0)=\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}=\frac{f(z)}{z}<0 $$ so we are done.

**Case (2):** For all $x<0$, $f(x)=0$. In this case, $f'(x)=0$ for all $x<0$, which implies that, by left sided derivatives and the fact that $f'$ is smooth, $f'(0)=0$. It then follows that,  since $f'(x)=0$ on $(-\infty,0]$, we have $f^{(n)}(x)=0$ for all $x\in(-\infty,0]$.

For $n=1$, define $z_1$ as the real number in $(0,1)$ such that $$f'(z_1)=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0}=1$$For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $z_{n+1}$ by the real number in $(0,z_n)$ such that $$f^{(n+1)}(z_{n+1})=\frac{f^{(n)}(z_n)-f^{(n)}(0)}{z_n-0}=\frac{f^{(n)}(z_{n})}{z_n}>0$$ whose existence is given by the mean value theorem. This defines the sequence $(z_n)$, which converges to $0$ and is strictly decreasing.

---

Edit 2: Continuing, we see that by definition, we have $$f^{(n+1)}(z_{n+1})=\frac{f^{(n)}(z_n)}{z_n}>f^{(n)}(z_n)$$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq 2$, since $0<z_n<1$, thus the sequence $f^{(n)}(z_n)$ is strictly increasing and always greater than or equal to $1$. Now, $f^{(n)}(0)=0$, but since $(z_n)$ can get arbitrarily close to $0$ and $f^{(n)}(z_n)\geq 1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $f^{(n)}(0)=0<1\leq f^{(n)}(z_n)$ for large enough $n$.

This is has almost shown that $f$ is not differentiable for some value of $n$, but I am not quite sure that it has exactly shown that. If it has, then we are done, as **Case (2)** cannot happen. I would like help either formalizing this or fixing this if it is not true.

---

This is where my argument, to me, seems to break down. Intuitively, the slope of the secant lines between $f^{(n)}(z_n)$ and $f^{(n)}(0)$ is increasing without bound as $n$ increases. My idea was to create a sequence of points which converged to $0$, but broke the differentiability at $0$. I would greatly appreciate any tips in proceeding, critiques of my proof outline, or alternative proof methods. Thank you in advance.

Edit 1: In **Case (2)**, I am not explicitly making any assumptions that would lead to a contradiction, but why is this proof going in that direction? Either **Case (2)** cannot happen, which I find intuitively true, but my intuition often fails me, or one of my assumptions in the beginning of **Case (2)** is false.

Edit: Just to close this off, one of my faulty assumptions was that I assumed the sequence I constructed converged to $0$, which it doesn't have to.

Comment: Is $n = 0$ allowed here? Otherwise, $f(x) = \frac{e^x - 1}{e - 1}$ would be a counterexample, since all derivatives are strictly positive.

Comment: @red_trumpet In the context of the problem statement, we are taking $\mathbb{N}$ to be all positive natural numbers. Also, is you function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$? or would it not matter?

Comment: If it is defined on $\mathbb C$ it is also defined on $\mathbb R$ ;)

Comment: @red_trumpet I don't think that is a counter example, since for your function $f$, for any value of $x<0$, we have $f(x)<0$, while we require $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That is A5 from https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2018s.pdf

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is actually a very hard question. So hard, that it appeared in the 2018 Putnam Exam.
There are lots of solutions to this and I do not know which one suits your knowledge best. So just [choose](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2018s.pdf).

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. – From [answer]

Comment: Okay, I will later